# Database connection not working with upgraded Azure pricing tier

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have a web app hosted at Azure (ASP.NET Core) and it makes calls to a SQL database hosted somewhere else (not on Azure).

If I use the Free Pricing Tier everything works fine. However, if I upgrade to another pricing tier (B1 in my case), I stop being able to connect to the SQL database.

I've added the connection string to the database in the configuration options of the web app.

I'm at a loss here - what could upgrading the pricing tier possibly do to my database connection? It is as if the connection string could no longer be read after upgrading the pricing tier.

Comment: There are a network features that allow you to control inbound and outbound traffic but I'm not aware of any default restriction that apply to Azure VMs. I guess your problem has nothing to do with changing the pricing tier and I fear it's impossible to answer with provided information. How do you know that you cannot connect? (exceptions, logs, ...)? Can you connect from SSMS? Are you sure, your app get's the right connection string? ...

Comment: I "solved" it by using an Azure SQL database instead - still not sure why it's not working with one from another provider.

Comment: Using the db from Azure should make a lot of sense here: a) it's faster (because it's "nearer") b) you're not forced to have the DB in public internet but can keep it in a private network.